# How to create an item_list base on the output

Tags: ansible

I have an issue to get the device id from the sdtout of the previous task with register: device_output. The content of this variable look like this:

```
changed: [mac100] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "-c"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:05.015598",
    "end": "2018-05-18 17:56:17.829547",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "xxxxxxxxxx -c",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "chdir": "/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2018-05-18 17:56:12.813949",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "[....] Waiting up to 5 seconds for iOS device to be connected\n[....] Found 3e194 (J82, iPad Air 2 (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB.\n[....] Found 6cc84 (J81, iPad Air 2, iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB.",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "[....] Waiting up to 5 seconds for iOS device to be connected",
        "[....] Found 3e194 (J82, iPad Air 2 (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB.",
        "[....] Found 6cc84 (J81, iPad Air 2, iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB."
    ]
}
```

My plan is to create an item list i.g. id_list of all device id (3e194 and 6cc84) from the output above so that I can use it for next task with loop

```
- name: do my task
  command: "do some thing {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ id_list }}"
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the devices we need to grab from your output are in the `stdout_lines` and `stdout`. here is a quick way to do it with regex filtering.

step 1: reformat the list stdout_lines to a new list, if you find on any of the elements the string to be in format:

`"[....] Found 3e194 <not important string following>`.

replace it with the `3e194`.

step 2: process this new list variable item by item, and if the content of the item is less than 6 chars (perhaps you want to match strings of exactly 5 length, up to you), its a valid device id, add it to the `final_list`.

playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    stdout_lines:
      - "[....] Waiting up to 5 seconds for iOS device to be connected"
      - "[....] Found 3e194 (J82, iPad Air 2 (GSM), iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB."
      - "[....] Found 6cc84 (J81, iPad Air 2, iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPad' connected through USB."

  tasks:

    - name: step 1
      set_fact:
        reformat_list: "{{ stdout_lines | map('regex_replace', '^(\\[....\\] Found )([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\\s)(.*)$', '\\2') | list }}"

    - name: step 2
      set_fact:
        final_list: "{{ final_list | default([]) + [ item ]}}"
      when: item | length < 6
      with_items:
        - "{{ reformat_list }}"

    - name: print
      debug:
        var: final_list
```

output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [step 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [step 2] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[....] Waiting up to 5 seconds for iOS device to be connected) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=3e194)
ok: [localhost] => (item=6cc84)

TASK [print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_list": [
        "3e194", 
        "6cc84"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *
```

you can play around with the regex filter, or the when condition to tune it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you @ilias-sp. Your solution works like a charm. Frankly, regex is my weakness so I need to learn more about it before working on these such issue.